# How to copy a file from local machine to a storage account using Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-files, terraform0.12+

I have created a storage account and created a file share in it too using Terraform. I want to copy some files from my local machine to that storage account using Terraform. Is that possible? If yes, then how?

Here is my code-

```
provider "azurerm" {
  # whilst the `version` attribute is optional, we recommend pinning to a given version of the Provider
  version = "=2.0.0"
  subscription_id = "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
  tenant_id = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azuretest"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "asdfghjklteststorage"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "sharename"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50

  acl {
    id = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx"

    access_policy {
      permissions = "rwdl"
      start       = "2020-05-10T09:38:21.0000000Z"
      expiry      = "2020-07-02T10:38:21.0000000Z"
    }
  }
}
resource "null_resource" "uploadfile" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {


  command = <<-EOT
  $storageAcct = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}" -Name "${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}"
   Set-AzStorageFileContent `
   -Context $storageAcct.Context `
   -ShareName "${azurerm_storage_share.example.name}" `
   -Source "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\Untitled.png" `
   -Path "Untitled.png"

  EOT

  interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) provisioner invokes a local executable after a resource is created. See [upload a file to Azure file share with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell#upload-a-file).

For example,

```
    resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
      name                 = "sharename"
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      quota                = 50

      acl {
        id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        access_policy {
          permissions = "rwdl"
          start       = "2020-05-10T09:38:21.0000000Z"
          expiry      = "2020-07-02T10:38:21.0000000Z"
        }
      }
    }

    resource "null_resource" "uploadfile" {

      provisioner "local-exec" {


      command = <<-EOT
      $storageAcct = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}" -Name "${azurerm_storage_account.example.name}"
       Set-AzStorageFileContent `
       -Context $storageAcct.Context `
       -ShareName "${azurerm_storage_share.example.name}" `
       -Source "C:\Users\xxx\terraform\test.txt" `
       -Path "test.txt"

      EOT

      interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
      }

}
```

Result

[image]

For more information, you could read [this blog](http://%20Getting%20Started%20with%20Terraform%20on%20Azure:%20Provisioners).

Comment: Can you tell me what will come in the Id section of acl block? which id is it referring to?

Comment: it is a client id that i use to deploy azure resource with terraform.

Comment: I added client id but i am getting an error - Error reading static website for AzureRM Storage Account "asdfghjklteststorage": accounts.Client#GetServiceProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:7d28c330-c01e-004f-3b31-303003000000\nTime:2020-05-22T12:03:53.5643484Z"

Comment: what is the role of your service principal？

Comment: Can you tell me which role is required?

Comment: The SP has a contributor role in this subscription. see [authenticating to Azure with SP](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#creating-a-service-principal). The [acl](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_share.html#acl) is optional, you could remove the acl block.

Comment: I tried removing the contributor role. I still see that error.

Comment: How do you authenticate to Azure provider? Could you show your code?

Comment: I have added my subscription id and tenant id as well

Comment: Could you show your code？ how and where do you run the terraform file？ is the error mentioned in the specfic line in your code ？ any screenshots？

Comment: Error is not mentioned in a specific line of code. After i run `terraform apply` i get that error. I guess subs id and tenant id is enough to authorize.

Comment: no could you show your full code？then i can run it on my side tomorrow

Comment: Where is your client id and client secret? Do you follow these steps to [configure the Service Principal in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming from Google, it's worth pointing out you that in early 2022 should now be able to use azurerm_storage_share_file. This worked great for me to upload a single file. To upload multiple files it looks like you will require multiple resources

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_share_file

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share_file" "example" {
  name             = "test.txt"
  storage_share_id = azurerm_storage_share.example.id
  source           = "${path.root}/TestFiles/test.txt"
}
```